# Representing Graphs in Java efficiently

Tags: java, graph

In many online sources and a textbook, they say graphs are represented as:

1. Each node stores list of its neighbors:

   class Graph{
        ArrayList allNodes;

   ```
   class Node{
    Integer id;
    ArrayList<Node> neighbors;
    Boolean visited;
    }
   ```
2. Or with adjacency lists as:

   ```
   class Graph{
      HashMap<Node,ArrayList<Node>> adjMap;
   }

   class Node{
       Integer id;
       Boolean visited;
   }
   ```

These various online sources claim we can just add a boolean flag to keep track of visited nodes. I think this is okay with C++ due to pointers but it does not work in Java. My problem is while implementing BFS, DFS, Topological Sort, and detecting a cycle using modified DFS I found the above method in Java to NOT work. If you want to keep track of visiting nodes, you add a boolean flag 'visited' to the class Node. But this flag is inconsistent across the entire Graph. To explain with an example, let's say we have a graph represented as (1) from above, we might have:

```
<Node> => ArrayList<nighbors>
1 => 2 , 3, 5
2 => 4
3 => 4, 5
```

When populating this graph from a file, I found that Java treats Node 4 that is pointed by Node 2 different from Node 4 that is pointed by Node 3. This is in-spite of overriding the equals() and hashCode() method.
Similarly, if the graph was represented as (2) above, the adjMap that has Node 4 multiple times in its ArrayList of neighbors and modifying the visited flag of Node 4 when visiting Node 2 was not remembered when Node 4 was encountered again when visiting node 3.

The solution that I did find to was was graph that is represented like this:

```
class Graph{
 public class Graph {
    // Graph is shown as Node -> List of neighbouring nodes
    HashMap<Node, ArrayList<Node>> adjMap = new HashMap<Node, ArrayList<Node>>();
    HashMap<Node, Boolean> isExploredMap = new HashMap<Node, Boolean>();
    Set<Node> allNodes = new HashSet<Node> ();
}

class Node{
 Integer id;
}
```

That is we keep another HashMap called isExploredMap that stores whether or not the node was visited. What concerns me is that it takes further O(N) space, unlike  the previous two recommended solutions that did not work for me. Can someone please explain how to get the first two solutions to overcome the inconsistent flag condition?
Alternatively, if that is not possible that I needed confirmation that my solution is an acceptable way of doing these things.

This is assuming that the input is read from a file that has each line as an edge, Eg:
1 2
2 3
1 4

Indicates Node 1 is connected to node 2 and node 4, node 2 is connected to node 3

Comment: `When populating this graph from a file, I found that Java treats Node 4 that is pointed by Node 2 different from Node 4 that is pointed by Node 3.` - I'm sorry, what? You are probably creating another object and that Node is in fact not the same.

Comment: Correct, but then if we do not create another object, then in the file when we encounter again the number 4, how do you store it without creating a new Node(4)?